# How to check whether the user has a bookmark (iPhone)

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile

For mobile web development: I am making a website which asks the user (on an iPhone or iPod Touch) to save the page as a bookmark on the homescreen.

I do not want to show this message when the user already has a bookmark, so how can I check that (preferably using JavaScript, I don't know any other way).

Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check it with JavaScript via `window.navigator.standalone`. Look [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1950-Detecting-iPhone-s-App-Mode-Full-Screen-Mode-For-Web-Applications.htm) for details.

```
if (("standalone" in window.navigator) &&!window.navigator.standalone) {
  // Show the text for adding it as a 'bookmark'/app on home screen.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this meta tag in your index file
`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`

EDIT: To clarify: when the user uses to bookmark to access the page, the message shouldn't be displayed anymore. I have used the JS project [Add 2 Home](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) with success